# call selector in parent from UITableView delegate class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, delegates

Ok, I've been on this for a couple of hours now and figured it was time to reach out.  For my first time I'm working with multiple tableviews (2) on one storyboard.  I setup the storyboard with its own view controller (main view controller). The first table I delegated to the main view controller as the common pattern.  For the second table view I setup a separate class as the delegate and delegated to for tableview and datasource.

Things look good, each tableview loads and displays the correct data, etc. All good so far.

Here is the rub, on the second tableview - the externally delegated one, I want to take an action when a row is selected via: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath blah,blah,blah.

the desired action is to initiate a segue to a new view controller that is connected to "main view controller". I have a selector in the main view controller that has the perform segue action (which otherwise works)

I can't figure out how to establish a connection back from the delegate to main view controller so I can call the correct selector which will then initiate the segue.  Typically between segues I use segue.parent..  segue.destination...., etc. They do not work in this situation. I can't segue from the delegate class because the segue is not connected to the delegate.

I've tried this approach but it does not work:
StartViewController:

```
VisitListDelegate = [[VisitsMainPageDelegate alloc] init];
[self.iboVisitsTableView  setDelegate:self.VisitListDelegate];
[self.iboVisitsTableView  setDataSource:self.VisitListDelegate];

LocalVisits *LV = [[LocalVisits alloc] init]; //datasource
VisitListDelegate.visits = [LV getLocalVisits]; //sets variable in delagate
```

Delegate class called VisitsMainPageDelegate

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class StartViewController;

@interface VisitsMainPageDelegate : UIViewController
    <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>  {

StartViewController *sourceParent;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) StartViewController *sourceParent;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *visits;
@end
```

then try to reference it like this:

```
[sourceParent jumpToVistDetailsForThisVisit:@"test"];
```

I do not get errors but it does not work.

Any help towards solving this would be much appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Have you assigned a value to sourceParent? ie `delegate.sourceParent = self;` in the ViewController.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I have a main view controller with 2 tableviews.  I then created a class called VisitsMainPageDelegate and in the main view controller I referenced it like this:

 VisitListDelegate = [[VisitsMainPageDelegate alloc] init];
    [self.iboVisitsTableView  setDelegate:self.VisitListDelegate];
    [self.iboVisitsTableView  setDataSource:self.VisitListDelegate];
    
    LocalVisits *LV = [[LocalVisits alloc] init];  //datasource
    VisitListDelegate.visits = [LV getLocalVisits];

I don't know how to make a reference back from the delegate class to the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate the delegate class, you need to give it a reference to the ViewController as follows:

```
[[VisitsMainPageDelegate alloc] init];
[self.iboVisitsTableView setDelegate:self.VisitListDelegate]; 
delegate.sourceParent = self;
```

The first two lines you already have - it is the last line which you need to add.